# php artisan migrate , access denied

Tags: migrate

I get these errors when I migrate

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_
schema.tables where table_schema = computersale and table_name = migrations)
```

and

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

my configurations:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'computersale'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

and

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=computersale
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I tried clearing the *cache* and *config* but didn't work.

Comment: You need to assign a user to that database.

Comment: when I try to register, it says:
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = Ali@me.com)